# CSS shape-margin, shape-outside not working

Tags: css, css-shapes

**CSS shape-margin** and **shape-outside** are not working on my system. I'm using the latest version of Chrome. And the only thing I can think of is that my OS is Windows 7. Should this be an issue?

Here is the [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/16vz3c2a/3/). However since it may just be working when you see it on your systems, below is what it looks like on my system. Would appreciate if someone could direct me to a way around the issue (that does not involve upgrading my OS, yet seeing the style as it was intended).

[image: shape-margin not working]

Am using the following code:

```html
<h2>Example of shape margin</h2>
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-6/128/Circle-icon.png" 
     style="float: left; max-height: 5em; margin-right: 0.5em; 
            -webkit-shape-margin: 12em; shape-margin: 12em;
            -webkit-shape-outside: circle(50%); shape-outside: circle(50%);">
<p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsu mlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem
  ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem
  ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum</p>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### How are the shapes created for shape-outside and shape-margin?

The [`shape-outside` property's reference box is always the `margin-box` of the element](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/#toc-reference-boxes). So when the imaginary circle is drawn with `shape-outside` property, it is drawn based on the size of element plus its margins. Once the shape is drawn, the `shape-margin` property is then used to draw a larger shape outside of it.

The below screenshot shows how they actually get created. The innermost circle is the actual image, the lighter blue one which is offset a little from the inner circle is the actual shape that is created using the shape outside property. It is offset slightly from the actual circle shape because again reference is the `margin-box` and since you've set only a `margin-right`, it gets offset to the right. The large outer circle is the shape that is drawn based on the `shape-margin` property. The radius of this circle will be 12em + .25em (margin-right/2) + the actual size of the element (roughly 80px x 80px).

[image]

---

#### Any limits on how large the imaginary shape created for shape-margin can be?

Now, the key thing to note is that the shape that is created by the `shape-margin` will always be limited to the `margin-box` of the element and so anything beyond it will get clipped. In this example, the entire shape is outside of the `margin-box` of the element and thus what we see ends up as just a square.

**Source for the above is [this HTML5Rocks article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/#toc-shape-margin):**

> Remember, the shape is ultimately constrained to the element’s margin-box (the element plus its surrounding margin)

In the below screenshot, the black square (created with a pseudo + a `div` wrapper) represents what is the margin-box area of the `img`.

[image]

```css
img {
  float: left;
  max-height: 5em;
  margin-right: .5em;
  -webkit-shape-margin: 12em;
  shape-margin: 12em;
  -webkit-shape-outside: circle(50%);
  shape-outside: circle(50%);
}

/* added just to indicate where margin box ends */

div {
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 80px;
  width: calc(.5em + 80px); /* 80px is width of element + .5em margin */
  border: 1px solid;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Example of shape margin</h2>
<div>
  <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-6/128/Circle-icon.png" style="">
  <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsu mlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem
    ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem
    ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

---

#### So, what is the solution?

This means for the `shape-margin` to work properly, the bigger circle (the reference for margin) should be created such that it is **contained within the margin-box** of the element.

---

**Option 1: Set shape-margin lower than margin-right**

This can either be done by setting the `shape-margin` such that it is less than the `margin-right` like in the below snippet.

```css
img {
  float: left;
  max-height: 5em;
  margin-right: .5em;
  -webkit-shape-margin: .15em;
  shape-margin: .15em;
  -webkit-shape-outside: circle(50%);
  shape-outside: circle(50%);
}
```

```html
<h2>Example of shape margin</h2>
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-6/128/Circle-icon.png" style="">
<p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsu mlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem
  ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem
  ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum</p>
```

---

**Option 2: Set margin-right larger than shape-margin**

Or, it could be done by setting a `margin-right` larger than the `shape-margin` value like in the below snippet.

```css
img {
  float: left;
  max-height: 5em;
  margin-right: 2.5em;
  -webkit-shape-margin: .25em;
  shape-margin: .25em;
  -webkit-shape-outside: circle(50%);
  shape-outside: circle(50%);
}
```

```html
<h2>Example of shape margin</h2>
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-6/128/Circle-icon.png" style="">
<p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsu mlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem
  ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem
  ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum</p>
```

But problem with second option is that as the `margin-right` increases, shape's radius also increases because the `margin-box` is the reference and so the `shape-margin` has to be very very smaller than the `margin-right`.

---

**Option 3: Set shape outside's reference as border-box and shape-margin same as margin-right**

Or,another option would be to set the reference box of `shape-outside` property to `border-box` of the `img` element. This would mean the size of shapes don't get affected by margins.

Another advantage of setting `border-box` as reference for the `shape-outside` property is that shape is not drawn at on offset (as margins again doesn't affect it).

```css
img {
  float: left;
  max-height: 5em;
  margin-right: 12em;
  -webkit-shape-margin: 12em;
  shape-margin: 12em;
  -webkit-shape-outside: circle(50%) border-box;
  shape-outside: circle(50%) border-box;
}
```

```html
<h2>Example of shape margin</h2>
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-6/128/Circle-icon.png" style="">
<p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsu mlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem
  ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem
  ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum</p>
```

> **Note:** There is actually a circular shape margin in the above snippet but that is not seen clearly because a portion of such a large circle is invariably almost a straight line. You can see the circle through Dev tools.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though `shape-margin` is causing the issue here. I must admit this isn't something I've tried before but using a normal `margin` instead of `shape-margin` seems to work:

```css
img {
  float: left;
  max-height: 5em;
  margin: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0;
  -webkit-shape-outside: circle(50%);
  shape-outside: circle(50%);
}
```

```html
<h2>Example of shape margin</h2>
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-6/128/Circle-icon.png">
<p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsu mlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem
  ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem
  ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum</p>
```

Comment: Beat me to it - even though MDN says Chrome supports `shape-margin` it only worked when a regular margin is applied.

Comment: If you check with the dev tools, you will see that it is making the shape bigger and not actualty making a margin around it

Comment: @Turnip - Yes, this is absolutely it - works. Thanks for coming with a solution too!

Answer (score 2):

> **Disclaimer :** *The [shape-outside](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside) property should not be used in live projects<sup>1</sup>. It may be subject to undesired behaviours.*

The problem seems to come from the fact that the [shape-margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-margin) is much bigger that the boundaries of the image. As you can see in this example, the shape-margin works :

```css
img {
  float: left;
  max-height: 5em;
  -webkit-shape-margin:1em;
  shape-margin:1em;
  -webkit-shape-outside: circle(25%);
  shape-outside: circle(25%);
}
```

```html
<h2>Example of shape margin</h2>
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-6/128/Circle-icon.png">
<p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsu mlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem
  ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem
  ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum</p>
```

If you need a big shape-margin, you can wrap the image in a div and apply the shape-outside and shape-margin properies to the div :

```css
.img {
  float: left;
  -webkit-shape-margin: 3.5em;
  shape-margin: 3.5em;
  -webkit-shape-outside: circle(2.5em);
  shape-outside: circle(2.5em);
}
.img img{
  max-height:5em;
  margin:3.5em;
}
```

```html
<h2>Example of shape margin</h2>
<div class="img">
  <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-6/128/Circle-icon.png">
</div>
<p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsu mlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem
  ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem
  ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum</p>
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>The [CSS Shapes Module Level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-shapes/) actualy (july 2015) has the status of "Candidate Recommendation". As this means it is a work in progress, it may change at any moment and therefore should not be used other than for testing.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Possibly it was an issue with the image you used but this seems to work...in Chrome.

Deleting this helped also:

```
-webkit-shape-margin: 12em; 
shape-margin: 12em;
```

```css
img {
  width: 5em;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-shape-outside: circle();
  shape-outside: circle();
}
```

```html
<h2>Example of shape margin</h2>
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/kiwifruit-on-a-plate.jpg" alt="A photograph of sliced kiwifruit on a while plate" />
<p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsu mlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem
  ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem
  ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum</p>
```

Comment: thanks, but actually the image you put in has a very clear square background around it; the image i'd picked i checked in photoshop for its background - and it was transparent, so that should not be the issue. Also, I do need the shape margin.

Comment: As I said it works fine in Chrome for me. If it doesn't for you it either a browser issue or prefixing.